# How do I use boost::transformed to modify a sequence using a lambda in a template construct?

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

I have a type `MyStruct` which I would like to produce some "sequence" from, where each instance of `MyStruct` is generated from passing to its constructor an element of another range as well as the output of some function.

The function itself (`SomeFun`) is a member function in another class, but for this example I'll make it a free function. However, keep in mind that I can's simply place it inside the lambda or do other tricky things to avoid the need for a lambda because I do need to actually pass a `this` pointer around in my actual case.

Here is a simplified, testable version to illustrate the problem I'm having:

```
#include <iostream>                                                             
#include <vector>                                                               
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>                                  

#include <functional>                                                           

template <typename RowType>                                                     
class MyStruct;                                                                 

template <typename T>                                                           
int SomeFun(T t)                                                                
{                                                                               
    return 0;                                                                   
}                                                                               

template <typename Sequence>                                                    
using Converter = std::function<                                                
    MyStruct<typename Sequence::value_type>(                                    
        typename Sequence::value_type&)>;                                       

template <typename Sequence>                                                    
boost::transformed_range<Converter<Sequence>, Sequence>                         
    GenerateTransformedRange(const Sequence& outputs)                           
{                                                                               
    std::function<MyStruct<typename Sequence::value_type>(int)> fun =           
        [](const typename Sequence::value_type output)                          
        {                                                                       
            return MyStruct<typename Sequence::value_type>(output, SomeFun(output));
        };                                                                      

    return outputs | boost::adaptors::transformed(fun);                         
}                                                                               

// some structure                                                               
template <typename T>                                                           
struct MyStruct                                                                 
{                                                                               
    MyStruct(T t, int a)                                                        
    {                                                                           
    }                                                                           
};                                                                              

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])                                          
{                                                                               
    std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3};                                             

    for (auto element : GenerateTransformedRange(vec))                          
    {                                                                           
    }                                                                           

    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

The output from this is:

> main.cpp:31:54: error: could not convert
>   ‘boost::range_detail::operator|(const InputRng&, const
>   boost::range_detail::transform_holder&) [with InputRng
>   = std::vector; UnaryFunction = std::function(int)>]((*(const
>   boost::range_detail::transform_holder(int)>
>
> > *)(& boost::range_detail::forwarder::operator()(T) const [with T = std::function(int)>; Holder =
> >     boost::range_detail::transform_holder](std::function(int)>((*(const
> >     std::function(int)>*)(& fun)))))))’ from
> >     ‘boost::range_detail::transformed_range(int)>,
> >     const std::vector >’ to
> >     ‘boost::range_detail::transformed_range(int&)>,
> >     std::vector >’
> >          return outputs | boost::adaptors::transformed(fun);
> >                                                           ^ makefile:25: recipe for target '.obj/main.o' failed

What am I doing wrong here? I don't quot understand why it wants to convert from that type. Any ideas? I'm using `Boost 1.55`.

Comment: The error message is completely unreadable. It is missing lots of template arguments. Format it as code rather than a quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error:

> test.cpp:29:20: error: no match for ‘operator|’ (operand types are ‘const std::vector’ and ‘std::function >(int)>’)
>        return outputs | fun;

should be perfectly clear. There is no `operator|` for operands `vector` and a `function`. Your second operand should be a boost adaptor which actually defines the operator. Probably like this:

```
return outputs | boost::adaptors::transformed(fun);
```

Also in this code:

```
std::function<MyStruct<Sequence>(int)> fun =
        [](const typename Sequence::value_type output)
        {
            return MyStruct<typename Sequence::value_type>(output, SomeFun(output));
        };
```

According to the type declaration, `fun` should return a `MyStruct<Sequence>` but your lambda returns a `MyStruct<typename Sequence::value_type>`. Also, you probably shouldn't hardcode the parameter type as `int` if the lambda expects a `Sequence::value_type`. You should probably declare `fun` as type `Converter<Sequence>`. Also, fix the parameter type of the lambda and the function to match with `Converter` (pay attention to the reference).

Comment: Sorry, I totally muddled up the test case. I've fixed up the obvious errors you pointed out, please refer to the updated question.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I can get your code to compile if I declare `GenerateTransformedRange` to return `auto` (c++1y feature). So I'm guessing that there is some mismatch among the declarations. Make sure that the parameter type matches exactly in your `fun`and `GenerateTransformedRange` declaration and the lambda.