# How do I use boost::adaptors::transformed to produce a range from a templated class and a vector?

Tags: c++, boost

I asked a question about using a lambda to achieve something similar earlier but [wasn't able to get this working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422993/how-do-i-use-boosttransformed-to-modify-a-sequence-using-a-lambda-in-a-templat) so I've tried approach the problem using a functor instead. This is probably neater anyway in the sense that it doesn't involve constructing `std::function` objects and is closer to the [example case set out in the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html).

Here is a simple setup that illustrates my problem:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <vector>

// some structure
template <typename T>
struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct(T t)
    {
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Converter
{
    using return_type = MyStruct<T>;

    return_type operator()(const T& value)
    {
        return return_type(value);
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3};

    auto val = vec | boost::adaptors::transformed(Converter<int>());

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this I am getting the following error message:

> /home/user/packages/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:38:31: error: no type named
>   ‘type’ in ‘`boost::mpl::eval_if<boost::is_same<boost::use_default,
>   boost::use_default>, boost::result_of<const Converter<int>(int&)>,
>   boost::mpl::identity<boost::use_default> >::f_ {aka struct
>   boost::result_of<const Converter<int>(int&)>}`’

I'm not sure what to make of this. I can't spot any errors in the code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error tells you `boost::result_of<const Converter<int>(int&)>` doesn't have the `type` member. In other words, the function call operator doesn't work when a `const Converter<int>` object is used. Once you know the problem, it's easy to see what's wrong:

```
return_type operator()(const T& value) const
//                                     ^^^^^
{
    return return_type(value);
}
```

Comment: Something so simple caused me a lot of grief! Thanks. How did you *know* that this error related to the `const` specifier?

Comment: @Arman The error is basically saying that if you have `const Converter<int> conv; int i;` then `conv(i)` doesn't work (in a really convoluted way, I know...). Once you understand what it's saying, then finding the problem in the code is easy.

Comment: @arman more concretely, suppose you where tood `boost::result_of<const Converter<int>(int&)>` failed, and that was your problem.  What would you do next?  Look up docs, play with it, remove `&`s from call, remove `const` -- wait, then it works.  The problem is the `const`.  How to fix?