# C++11 How to use lambda and higher order functions to transform a vector to a vector of different type

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, lambda, stl

Is there a way to return a vector of a different type using higher order functions in C++11? I have a `std::vector<std::string>` and want to convert this into a `std::vector<Foo>` which is an enum of my own device.

Assume I have a method `Foo toFoo(std::string)`. I've tried:

```
std::vector<Foo> m_Foos = std::for_each(m_Foo_strings.begin(),
        m_Foo_strings.end(), 
        [this](std::string &s){ toFoo(s); } );
```

And also tried:

```
std::vector<Foo> m_Foos = std::transform(m_Foo_strings.begin(),
        m_Foo_strings.end(),
        m_Foo_strings.begin(), 
        [this](std::string &s){ toFoo(s); } );
```

But neither compiles. It complains about no operator= defined from std::string to Foo.

There has to be a common way to do what I'm trying here, what am I missing?

Comment: Any documentation would quickly tell you what parameters and return type those functions have.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html +++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437768/how-do-i-use-boostadaptorstransformed-to-produce-a-range-from-a-templated-cl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) does not return a `vector`, it applies the specified transformation and stores the results in the destination range you pass it

```
std::transform(m_Foo_strings.begin(),
               m_Foo_strings.end(),
               std::back_inserter(m_Foos),
               [this](std::string &s){ return toFoo(s); } );
```

[`back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) constructs a `back_insert_iterator` which will call `vector::push_back` to add elements to `m_Foos` when `transform` assigns the result of the call to the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<Foo> m_Foos;
std::for_each(m_Foo_strings.begin(),
              m_Foo_strings.end(), 
              [this, &m_Foos](std::string &s){ m_Foos.push_back(toFoo(s)); } );
```

Comment: This looks promising, is it guaranteed that for_each traverses in the same order as the initial vector? So m_Foo_strings and m_Foos will be in the same order?

Comment: Yes. See the [documentation of `std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each). "Applies the given function object f to the result of dereferencing every iterator in the range [first, last), **in order**."

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a range-based for loop. This works if you're iterating from `begin` to `end`, but you'd need to use the either `for_each` or `transform` if you only wanted to work on a subset.

```
std::vector<Foo> m_Foos;
for (const auto& s : m_Foo_strings) {
    m_Foos.push_back(toFoo(s));
}
```